# How to extract words in text without special characters python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to extract word from this data frame

```
statutInit     
Majoration : 0,06‰ Capital
```

The output I want

```
    statutInit                    statute                 taux
  Majoration : 0,06‰ Capital    Majoration Capital      0,06‰
```

Thank!!

Comment: Please describe what you want in greater detail. Also, please provide some more sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a text(with names and values) column into multiple columns in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973170/split-a-textwith-names-and-values-column-into-multiple-columns-in-pandas-dataf)

Comment: No, this post does not answer my question

Comment: if rest of your data looks similair, you can use `regex` (regular expressions) to extract particular parts of string (look for `re` package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['statute'] = [re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', val.strip()) for val in df['statutInit']]
df['statute'] = [' '.join(val) for val in df['statute']]

df['taux'] = [re.split(r'[a-zA-Z:\s]+', val.strip()) for val in df['statutInit']]
df['taux'] = [''.join(val) for val in df['taux']]


print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    statutInit             statute   taux
0  Majoration : 0,06‰ Capital   Majoration Capital  0,06‰
```